# Setting up CSGO dedicated server with Hamachi

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, hosting, server-administration

I installed a csgo dedicated and then i added a server.cfg, installed sourcmod and metamod. When i was done i connected to xx.xx.xxx.xx:27015 but i couldn't connect.
I got the error "Disconnected after 30 retries", am i doing something wrong?

**What i've tried**

- I tried setting the server lan to both 0 and 1
- I tried setting the server ip and netaddr to 0.0.0.0
- I tried connecting via localhost

Have i done something wrong?

**Edit**

http://pastebin.com/qZPzKVcB - Contains Server.cfg and Start.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find out your external IP address. Google "what is my ip address" and Google will tell you what it is. Give that as the `+ip` and `+net_public_addr` parameters, and try connecting on that IP address + port.